# CartThrob Edit Permission Item - Submit button doesn't do anything

Tags: cartthrob, permissions

If I create a permission item (i.e. `CartThrob` > `Add-Ons` > `Create permission item`) and then save it.  Everything seems to work as expected.

However, when I enter "edit" mode and then try to `Submit`, absolutely nothing happens...

Google Chrome Inspector does not show any errors and there is no Network activity going on either.

> Expression Engine version 2.7.3
>
> CartThrob version 2.4

Let me know if I can provide any further details to help debug this.

Thanks.

> **UPDATE:**
>
> Upon further investigation it appears there is no opening `<form>` tag.  Does anyone know where this file is located or have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new Cartthrob Permissions Admin module (version 2.5) was released today. It should fix the "edit" problem.

Comment: The update did not appear to fix the issue.  I have setup a support ticket through http://support.mightybigrobot.com/ as you mentioned on another question I have.  Can we address this during that appointment?

Comment: With help from CartThrob, reinstalling version 2.5 fixed the issue.